# Unable to click elements inside the frame

Tags: selenium

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));
try
{
    System.out.println(186);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btn_submit']")).click();
    System.out.println(188);
}
```

Above code will redirect to frame and it also print line number 186 but after that element of frame are not working

Comment: Plase describe what are you aiming to do, and what have you tried.

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: I am trying to switch to frame and click submit button listed inside of that frame. Previously it works for me but now same code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iframe");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btn_submit']")).click();
```

Comment: Yes I already tried this solution but it does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed after I changed implicitylyWait to thread.sleep();

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

to:

```
thread.sleep(5000);
```